# Convert python string with newlines and tabs to dictionary

Tags: python, string, dictionary, split

I'm a bit stuck with this particular problem I'm having. I have a working solution, but I don't think it's very Pythonic.

I have a raw text output like this:

```
Key 1   
  Value 1 
Key 2   
  Value 2 
Key 3   
  Value 3a  
  Value 3b
  Value 3c 
Key 4   
  Value 4a  
  Value 4b
```

I'm trying to make a dictionary:

```
{ 'Key 1': ['Value 1'], 'Key 2': ['Value 2'], 'Key 3': ['Value 3a', 'Value 3b', 'Value 3c'], 'Key 4': ['Value 4a', 'Value 4b'] }
```

The raw output can be made into a string and it looks something like this:

```
my_str = "
Key 1\n\tValue 1
\nKey 2\n\tValue 2
\nKey 3\n\tValue 3a \n\tValue 3b \n\tValue 3c
\nKey 4\n\tValue 4a \n\tValue 4b "
```

So the Values are separated by \n\t and the Keys are separated by \n

If I try to do something like this:

```
dict(item.split('\n\t') for item in my_str.split('\n'))
```

It doesn't parse it correctly because it splits the 'n' in \n\t as well.

So far I have something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

str = "Key 1\n\tValue 1\nKey 2\n\tValue 2\nKey 3\n\tValue 3a \n\tValue 3b \n\tValue 3c\nKey 4\n\tValue 4a \n\tValue 4b"

output = str.replace('\n\t', ',').replace('\n',';')
result = {}
for key in output.split(';'):
  result[key.split(',')[0]] = key.split(',')[1:]
print result
```

Which returns:

```
{'Key 1': ['Value 1'], 'Key 2': ['Value 2'], 'Key 3': ['Value 3a ', 'Value 3b ', 'Value 3c'], 'Key 4': ['Value 4a ', 'Value 4b']}
```

However, this looks quite gross to me, I'm just wondering if there is a pythonic way to do this. Any help would be super appreciated!

Comment: And I see that you found it on your own now. You now ask it it's "Pythonic". Does it work? If so, then, who cares?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Batteries are included - `defaultdict` deals with auto-hydrating a new key's value as a list and we leverage `str`'s `iswhitespace` method to check for indentation (otherwise we could have used a regular expression):

```
from collections import defaultdict

data = """
Key 1   
  Value 1 
Key 2   
  Value 2 
Key 3   
  Value 3a  
  Value 3b
  Value 3c 
Key 4   
  Value 4a  
  Value 4b
"""

result = defaultdict(list)
current_key = None

for line in data.splitlines():
    if not line: continue  # Filter out blank lines

    # If the line is not indented then it is a key
    # Save it and move on
    if not line[0].isspace():
        current_key = line.strip()
        continue

    # Otherwise, add the value
    # (minus leading and trailing whitespace)
    # to our results
    result[current_key].append(line.strip())

# result is now a defaultdict
defaultdict(<class 'list'>,
    {'Key 1': ['Value 1'],
     'Key 2': ['Value 2'], 
     'Key 3': ['Value 3a', 'Value 3b', 'Value 3c'],
     'Key 4': ['Value 4a', 'Value 4b']})
```

Comment: Alternatively, you can make your `result` a regular dictionary, and then change `result[current_key].append(line.strip())` to `result.setdefault(current_key, []).append(line.strip())`.  (I use `collections.defaultdict` frequently, but sometimes I wonder at its usefulness when all I use it for is to avoid single call to `setdefault`.)

Answer (score 1):

[`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) is useful here.  You can group adjacent lines by their indent, then insert adjacent indented lines to a dict in one go using `extend`:

```
my_str = """Key 1\n\tValue 1\nKey 2\n\tValue 2\nKey 3\n\tValue 3a \n\tValue 3b \n\tValue 3c\nKey 4\n\tValue 4a \n\tValue 4b"""

def get_indent(line):
    return len(line) - len(line.lstrip())

res = {}
for indent, tokens in itertools.groupby(my_str.splitlines(), lambda line: get_indent):
    if indent == 0:
        cur_key = list(tokens)[0]
        res[cur_key] = []
    else:
        res[cur_key].extend( token.strip() for token in tokens )

print(res)
{'Key 3': ['Value 3a', 'Value 3b', 'Value 3c'],
 'Key 4': ['Value 4a', 'Value 4b'],
 'Key 2': ['Value 2'],
 'Key 1': ['Value 1']}
```

Answer (score 0):

I find that whenever one starts chaining together a bunch of operations in a single line (as in your "result.setdefault..." line), you muddy up what may be very simple problem.

```
str = "Key 1\n\tValue 1\nKey 2\n\tValue 2\nKey 3\n\tValue 3a \n\tValue 3b \n\tValue 3c\nKey 4\n\tValue 4a \n\tValue 4b"

output = str.replace('\n\t', ',').replace('\n',';')
result = {}
for group in output.split(';'):
    values = group.split(',')
    key = values[0]
    result[key] = []
    for v in values[1:]:
        result[key].append(v)
print result
```

Yields:

```
{'Key 1': ['Value 1'], 'Key 2': ['Value 2'], 'Key 3': ['Value 3a ', 'Value 3b ', 'Value 3c'], 'Key 4': ['Value 4a ', 'Value 4b']}
```

Comment: Of course, be careful that you won't have commas or semi-colons in any of your data.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously you cannot remove the \n and \t from your raw text output, however you might have the possibility to add/include more chars in it such that this

```
Key 1     
  Value 1   
Key 2     
  Value 2 
Key 3  
  Value 3a  
  Value 3b
```

will look like this

```
"Key 1":[      
  Value 1   
],   
"Key 2":[     
  Value 2  
],  
"Key 3":[
  Value 3a,  
  Value 3b
]
```

Then you can use the json parser in the following way

```
import json    
myDict = json.loads(my_str)
```